# HighCharts gauge big figure and congested percentage issues

Tags: charts, highcharts, pentaho, gauge

I am having follow issues in the highchart gauges:

1. Sales Revenue the gauges does not start with the ranges i have assigned to it check Sales/Revenue block, ranges that i provide to the gauge is:
   511721.61  604761.90  604761.91     744322.34   744322.35    1116483.52
2. another issue is in the profit percentage block, ranges are too closely bound. does not look good, ranges are, 40.01      41.87      41.88         44.19       44.20        46.52
3. third issue is if the dialer figure is exceeding the range values, the needle circles over the dialer again and stops on a wrong figure, i want that if the needle should not recircle and stop on the end of the green end.

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/9mcw95bf/1/

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/9mcw95bf/1/][2]
```

Comment: 2. Use tickPoisitions with the array of values where the ticks should appear. After it, use label formatter to filter labels, so they will not appear to close.
3. Set wrap property to false
1. I am not sure If I understand you correctly, but if you have a value from the gauge should start set yAxis.im to that value.
https://jsfiddle.net/9mcw95bf/7/

Comment: @morganfree but i don't want just start and end points on the color circle. i want atleast one the in the middle as well :(

Comment: So add another tick in the tickPositions array - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions